# ASP.NET Javascript runtime error

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have just started a new ASP.NET web application and I am totally new to everything and after moving a few things round I have been getting this error and I don't understand what it means.

It happens when I go to enter anything in the Password box.

[image]

Could someone please help me out on this issue.

EDIT:

```
    <li>
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" onkeypress="capLock(event)" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
    </li>
```

Comment: Please provide your actual code; an image of the error will not help us to help you.

Comment: i think that it's not able to find the element divMayus in your page other wise please provide your code snippet to know the problem

Comment: `Unable to get property "style" of undefined` is stating just that. What ever the part is that `.style` is called on is undefined. Why, that element is undefined is a separate issue all together and cannot be determined without the **relevant** HTML **and** Script. If possible create a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net)(or similar)  to demonstrate the issue. In most cases doing just that will help you already solve your issue as you are condensing your code to a [**minimal example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Relevant meaning the part of the code `divMayus` is the ID of.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Code snippet added,

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("divMayus")` is returning null or undefined.

You should look at the rendered html and find the div that you are trying to reference to make sure the id is the same as you are trying to reach.  Asp.net alters the ids of server controls depending on their containers.  So if you moved stuff around, the id may have also been changed.

Comment: Thanks that has helped me out enough :)

Comment: @user3507542, I've added a little more detail to my answer on what may have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that inside

```
window.onload = function(){
  // code goes here
}
```

I think you are trying to access DOM even before it is being created.

the `document.getElementById('divMayus')` is `undefined`

Comment: I have added code for my Password box but used the premade ASP.NET solutions so I don't understand why it wouldn't work.